# Factually, what proportion of companies make today (31st) a holiday?

Tags: holidays

Let's set aside very small companies (let's say, under 20 or so people).

"Most" companies seem to have January 1 as a holiday day - the company is closed.

What about Monday December 31, 2018 ?

- Is there any statistics on this?
- It would be good to know in the USA, and indeed, the contrasting situation in other world regions.

{Some nations of course have no holidays at all for Xmas, but what about the New Year .... and to the question at hand, the "last day of the year" .. ?)

Comment: That probably can't be answered 'factually' as you'd have to survey every company in business.  Anecdotally, while not technically a holiday in most organizations, 31 DEC is a practical holiday/half-day for many professional jobs, meaning non-retail, because you can make it a 4-day weekend.

Comment: I've never worked at a company that had the 31st as a holiday.  Nor has my spouse.  So there are about 10-15 data points for you.  (I'm a geek, he's a scientist.)

Comment: Using my company as a data point and extrapolating, it's 100%. Using my company and the supermarket I visited this morning, it's 50%.

Comment: 0% for my work history but I doubt their is any source of reliable statistics in the large for this.

Comment: My company trades a bunch of (minor) Federal (US) holidays to give us Christmas to New Years off. Well, except for the facility folks doing heavy maintenance activities (e.g.replacing a sub station). Quite nice actually.

Comment: every company is different

Comment: @Johns-305 ? you'd seem to be totally incorrect. The Society for Human Resource Management apparently publishes actual figures, as you'd expect some such body or government agency would.

Comment: @Fattie Sorry, no :(  But Happy New Year!  Note: my observation from many years in many businesses is pretty much in line with the **58** respondents in that survey...**yes, 58**.  Science!  The closest analog to New Year's Eve this year would be this data point: Day after Thanksgiving: Friday, November 24 (Offices Closed) 75%

Comment: In my country they're both (and Christmas) mandated holidays, unless you are in the service industry or providing essential goods, you're not allowed to open for business. So some supermarkets are open, hotels etc,. still operate, and some grocery stores and essential govt services, but that's about it. Happy New Year.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For 2017, according to the Society for Human Resource Management (SHRM),

- On New Year's Eve (a Sunday in 2017) 44% of offices expected to be closed, 10% expected to close early, 46% expected to remain open.
- On the Saturday before New Year's Eve, 33% of offices expected to be closed, 2% expected to close early, 65% expected to remain open.
- On the Friday before New Year's Eve, 20% of offices expected to be closed, 10% expected to close early, 70% expected to remain open.

I don't believe the numbers for 2018 are publicly available yet. It would clearly change depending on which day of the week on which New Year's Eve landed.

https://www.shrm.org/hr-today/trends-and-forecasting/research-and-surveys/Documents/SHRM-Survey-Findings-2017-Holiday-Schedules.pdf

Back in 2012, New Year's Eve was on a Monday. The same survey found:

- On New Year's Eve (a Monday in 2012) 34% of offices expected to be closed, 22% expected to close early, 43% expected to remain open.

Obviously, practices could have changed since then.

https://www.slideshare.net/shrm/2012-holiday-schedule-final

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the country. Many countries designate Jan 1 as a public holiday, so only some retailers and pubs/clubs would be open.

Some companies may have mandatory holidays at that time, e.g. closing between Christmas Eve or Christmas Day and returning to work on Jan 2, where employees are required to use their accrued annual leave for non-public holiday days, but this wouldn't be universal.

Wikipedia has a list of public holidays by country, which contains links to mandatory public holidays by country: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minimum_annual_leave_by_country